# Solve: $-3(6t^3-1)^6 -3t[6(6t^3-1)^5(18t^2)]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Solve:  $-3(6t^3-1)^6 + -3t[6(6t^3-1)^5(18t^2)]$

I don't know how to multiply the two equations and then add them.

Comment: Have you tried to extract the common factor?

Comment: In your question, you have $+-$.  Should that just be $-$ like the title?  What are you solving?  I don't see an equation.  Are you really asked to simplify, or factor, or what?  One thing you could do is just multiply it out and get a polynomial.

Comment: I am trying to multiply these two as part of the product rule in finding the derivative. I still have not figured this one out.

Comment: I am wanting to multiply each and then add them together.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by factoring out $(6t^3-1)^5$ leaving you with

$(6t^3-1)^5[-3-6(6t^3-1)54t^3]$

Can you work it out from there?

Comment: You introduced a negative sign that was not in the original problem or omitted a set of parentheses that were in the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A = 6t^3-1$.

\begin{align} -3(6t^3-1)^6 + -3t[6(6t^3-1)^5(18t^2)] &= -3A^6-3t(108A^5t^2) \\
&= -3A^6-324A^5t^3\\
&=-3A^5(A+108t^3)\\
&=-3(6t^3-1)^5[(6t^3-1)+108t^3]\\
&=-3(6t^3-1)^5(114t^3-1)\\
\end{align}

So $t=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{6}}, \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{114}}.$